# Se puede agregar un valor por defecto a un input file?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

me gustaría saber si puedo agregar a un input de tipo file una imagen por defecto... algo así como

```
<input type="file" value="imagen.png" name="opcionesImg[]" :id="'input'+index + 1" style="display: none;">
```

Cuando pongo esto no me funciona... alguna idea de como puedo hacer esto?
Ya se que no se deberia trabajar este tipo de cosas de esta manera pero la situación a merita...

Comment: La única forma de asignar `value` a un `<input type=file/>` es que el usuario seleccione un archivo

Comment: Puedes usar un framework en el front como por ejemplo angular y en el controlador creas un modelo con un atributo, el que quieres settear y ese atributo lo llamas en el html (vista)

Comment: en todo caso como podria enviar una imagen por defecto en caso de que in mi input este vacio?

Comment: Hernan, es relativamente simple asignar una imagen por defecto en el lado servidor si en el request no llega un archivo de imagen. Creo que te estás complicando queriendo hacerlo en el lado cliente.

Comment: no se que estes usando en concreto, pero si usas js deberias hacer una validacion con un if, si el input es vacio mandas una variable por defecto, por ejemplo, debes poner un id al input y en el js debes hacer algo como: var caja_texto = getElementById('id_que_pusiste_en_el?input') y luego con un if validas si es vacio con un trim y ademas si no es nulo

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta es NO, ya que tener un valor predeterminado para este tipo de input daría como resultado una vulnerabilidad respecto al contenido de ese directorio local. *Seria un inconveniente enorme dar referencia a un directorio físico del servidor*.

Pero puedes hacer algunos "**artificios**" de forma que puedas conseguir un resultado como el que esperas.

Como por ejemplo en caso de no subir ninguna imagen(el input quedaría con un String vacío, osea "") podrías evaluar este valor, en caso de que no se haya seleccionado nada podrías asignar una imagen de forma automática sin necesidad de tomar el valor del input.

te dejo esta informacion respecto a esta etiqueta y los tipos que tiene:
[INFO-INPUT](http://usuaris.tinet.cat/acl/html_web/manual/formularios/formularios_3.html)

Answer (score 0):

A ver lo que yo hago es lo siguiente. Debes de tener una imagen por defecto en tu servidor en mi caso la llamo default.jpg

```html
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
  if (isset($_FILES['file-up1']['name'])){
     /* subimos la imagen */
  }else{
    $imagen = "default.jpg";
    return $imagen;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En caso de que el formulario envie una imagen por escogida del servidor automaticamente, ya lo he hecho con texto, pero con imagenes no se. Lo que quiero es que cuando alguien pregunte por un producto a traves del formulario, le llege la imagen del producto. Pense que se podia poniendo un "value" al input type"file", pero ya veo que no...
como lo puedo hacer?