# Obtener la ruta de una imagen y cargarla en un input type file (Laravel)

Tags: html, laravel

Tengo un CRUD de productos en Laravel  en el que guardo la imagen en una carpeta y al momento de editar necesito que en el input type file cargue la ruta en la que se encuentra la imagen. Por ejemplo, si solo quiero editar el nombre del producto e intento guardar no puedo ya que el input no tiene ningun archivo seleccionado.

Comment: no se puede asignar value a un <`input type="file>`. Deberás buscar otra aproximacón al problema. Mira [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/264271/se-puede-agregar-un-valor-por-defecto-a-un-input-file) por ejemplo

Comment: Gracias, lo revisaré

Comment: De nada. Si reformulas la pregunta y pones el código de lo que has hecho, tendrás mas posibilidades de que alguien pueda responderte.